# Redux-form onChange not trigger correctly on the form

Tags: javascript, react-redux, redux-form

I'm using reduxForm.

I created component with

```
<form>
    <Field name="example" component="SomeCustomInputComponent" type="text"/>
</form>
```

And I apply whole component to reduxForm with onChange function :

```
export default reduxForm({
    form: 'settingsAuthorization',
    destroyOnUnmount: false,
    forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true,
    enableReinitialize: true,
    onChange: (value, dispatch, props) => {
        console.warn(value);
    }
})(component);
```

And after putting some values I the onChane action doesn't do anything.

The funniest thing is that I tried to debug usage of my onChange function and I noticed that :
[Debbug IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Siy2h.png)

Here nextProps.values are the same like this.props.values. And also when I change content on the form. Values of nextProps and this.props. are as initialized.

But on the redux devtool site I get information about dispatched redux-form/CHANGE action :

> @@redux-form.CHANGE

And I can see that the form values are changed inside of global store (store.form.form_name.values.name) :

> form -> form_name -> values -> name : 'old Name' => 'new Name'

Also when I put :

```
onChange: (value, dispatch, props) => {
        console.warn(value);
    }
```

property for other form which I have on my site everything goes well.

How I can fix my first for for reacting on change event by using react-redux ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the form reducer to your redux reducers so your form state is stored and updated in the redux store.
Docs on how to do this [here](http://redux-form.com/7.0.3/docs/api/Reducer.md/)

If you aren't using redux for anything else, you'll need to `createStore`, and wrap your app in the react-redux `Provider`, more on that [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#passing-the-store)

Comment: I did. But I didnt mention about it. Thanks for your comment.